# get the arguments with which a spy was called

Tags: jasmine, angular6, angular-test

I am spying on method `emit` of `EventEmitter` in `Angular`

```
spyOn(answerComponent.answerEmitter, 'emit');
```

I want to check that `emit` was called with an argument `A` but I don't want to check exact match with `A`. I want to check that `emit` was called with values `A.a, A.b` and ignore value of `A.c`.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 5):

Use [jasmine.objectContaining](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/jasmine#.objectContaining).

```js
const emit = spyOn(answerComponent.answerEmitter, 'emit');
expect(emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining({ a: <value>, b: <value>));
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways come to my mind:

One by using the native `toHaveBeenCalledWith`

```
expect(answerComponent.answerEmitter, 'emit').toHaveBeenCalledWith(A.a);
expect(answerComponent.answerEmitter, 'emit').toHaveBeenCalledWith(A.b);
// you can think of all the callers being tracked as an array and you can assert with
// toHaveBeenCalledWith to check the array of all of the calls and see the arguments
expect(anserComponent.anserEmitter, 'emit').not.toHaveBeenCalledWith(A.c); // maybe you're looking for this as well
```

You can also spy on the emit and call a fake function:

```
spyOn(answerComponent.answerEmitter, 'emit').and.callFake((arg: any) => {
  // every time emit is called, this fake function is called
  if (arg !== A.a || arg !== A.b) {
     throw 'Wrong argument passed!!'; // you can refine this call fake
  }  // but the point is that you can have a handle on the argument passed and assert it
});
```